# Kubernetes: list a node's all pods and pod statuses

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I want to list a node's pods and pod statues, eg.

```
Node A
Pod1 Status
Pod2 Status

Node B
Pod1 Status
Pod2 Status
```

Is there a `kubectl` command I can use for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:
`kubectl get pods -A  --field-selector spec.nodeName=<node name> | awk '{print $2"  "$4}'`

Answer (score 3):

```
kubectl get pods
```

will give you almost what you want, but it has no `Node` information, that is why you would need `-o wide` (I doubt you really want the `-A` parameter here); then you need a bit of `awk`. So may be like this:

```
kubectl get pods -o wide  | awk '{print $1"  "$3"  "$7}
```

Answer (score 3):

This script gives exactly the output you want:

```sh
kubectl get --no-headers pods --all-namespaces -o wide > /tmp/allpods

while read node; do
    echo "${node/node\//}"
    grep " ${node/node\//} " /tmp/allpods | \
        while read line; do
            set -- $line
            echo "$2 $4"
        done
done < <(kubectl get nodes --no-headers --output=name)
```

But this version has a more readable output in my opinion:

- first column: k8s node name
- second column: namespace/pod-name
- third column: pod status

```sh
kubectl get --no-headers pods --all-namespaces -o wide > /tmp/allpods

while read node; do
    echo "${node/node\//}"
    while read line; do
        set -- $line
        echo " $2 $4"
    done < <(grep " ${node/node\//} " /tmp/allpods)
done < <(kubectl get nodes --no-headers --output=name) | column -t -s ' '
```

Output:

```
k8s-node01
            my-namespace01/mypod01-321-86d58674d8-kv222         Completed
            my-namespace01/mypod01-321-redis-55dc88454c-z6xfj   Running
            [...]
k8s-node02
            [...]
```

Doing an API call for each cluster node, as the accepted answer suggests, makes the script execution very long in a production environment with dozens of nodes and thousands of pods. That's why I opted for a solution where the result of a single call is saved to a temporary file.

Comment: stackoverflow at its finest, your answer is by far the best here and yet no one seemed to care. I especially loved the `column -t -s ' '`. btw, why `set -- $line echo " $2 $4"`, instead of an `awk`?

Comment: Thanks! Because `set` is a bash internal. Why using external binaries (that need forking, loading, piping,...) while bash can do the job?

Comment: I am by far no bash expert, my point is only from a readability angle. Thank you